# let fragment know when a certain listview item is on screen

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter.  I would like to run a specific method in the fragment when certain elements in the ArrayList are scrolled to and are displayed via `getView()`.

Is there a way to have my custom ArrayAdapter call a method directly on the fragment object that created it?  Or is there a way for the fragment to listen for a certain array element being displayed?

Here is my fragment code that instantiates the ArrayAdapter :

```
private void initAdapter() {
    infoViewAdapter infoAdapter = new infoViewAdapter(getActivity(), myInfo);

    infoListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    infoListView.setAdapter(infoAdapter);
}
```

And here is `getView()` in my custom adapter :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null) {
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.piece_of_info, parent, false);
    }

    myInfo currentInfo = getItem(position);

    TextView infoWordsText = listItem.findViewById(R.id.infoWordsView);
    TextView infoGotoText = listItem.findViewById(R.id.infoGoto);

    ImageView infoImage = listItem.findViewById(R.id.infoImageView);
    if (currentInfo.pic != -1) {
        // info block
        infoWordsText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        infoImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        infoGotoText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        infoWordsText.setText(currentInfo.words);
        infoImage.setImageResource(currentInfo.pic);
    } else {
        // category header
        infoWordsText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        infoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        infoGotoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        infoGotoText.setText(currentInfo.words);

        // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO CALL A METHOD ON THE FRAGMENT THAT CREATED ME
        // OR HAVE THE FRAGMENT REALIZE A CERTAIN ARRAY ELEMENT HAS BEEN DISPLAYED
    }

    return listItem;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work but you could try passing a reference to your context as a constructor parameter, then using the object instance to execute a method, something like context.this.mymethod();

Comment: A context is passed into the ArrayAdapter constructor, but since it is being constructed by a fragment, the context passed in is `getActivity()`, and it doesn't seem to let me call a fragment method using the activity context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback.

```
public interface OnGetView {
   void execute(int position);
}
```

Create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private OnGetView callback;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects, OnGetView callback) {
       super(context, resource, objects);
       this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(..) {
       process...
       callback.execute(position); // Should use thread here to not block ui thread if your callback is long-running task
    }
}
```

When init the adapter, pass a callback via that constructor and you're set.

```
// In your fragment
OnGetView myCallback = new OnGetView() {
    @Override
    void execute(int position) {
       ... your logic
    }
};
```

or

```
OnGetView myCallback = () -> { your logic};
```

Then pass it to your custom array adapter:

```
new CustomArrayAdapter(...., myCallback);
```

Comment: Cool, that is something I was poking around looking at how to do.  I was also thinking of creating an ArrayList with the TextViews I want to update and passing them into the ArrayAdapter constructor, but I like this callback approach better.

Comment: I am glad it helped you

Comment: So, I place the `public interface` in my fragment code (the class that has the method I want called).  And the `callback.execute()` in my custom ArrayAdapter class.  But don't I need to implement `execute()` somewhere?  I'm getting errors in my ArrayAdapter that it can't resolve `OnGetView`.

Comment: You need to import that `OnGetView` class to your CustomArrayAdapter. It's standard java thing dude. You also need to implement your execute logic, and pass it to custom adapter.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still fairly new to Java.  I've worked with callbacks in Unity, but not on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite get the callback Manh showed me to work...it is just a little beyond my Java knowledge at the moment, but I was able to get the approach suggested in the comments by Karan Modi to work.  In addition to the activity context which my code already passed into my custom ArrayAdapter constructor, I also included a reference to the fragment instance itself :

```
infoViewAdapter infoAdapter = new infoViewAdapter(getActivity(), myInfo, this);
```

and my constructor :

```
infoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MordorInfo> list, FeaturedFragment cb) {
    super (context, 0, list);
    myContext = context;
    infoList = list;
    featuredCallback = cb;
}
```

and then to call the fragment's method :

```
if (featuredCallback != null) {
    featuredCallback.setButtonCallback(currentInfo.gotoRef);
}
```

Works like a charm.  Are there any drawbacks for this approach?